# Multiple Column Sorting With dgrid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

How can I change the default behavior of `grid.js::_setSort()` in order to correctly display the sort criteria (up/down arrow) in the header of all the columns involved in a sort? Currently, `_setSort()` only deals with the first column of the array passed to `grid.set("sort")`. For example, after setting the sort criteria with the following command, only the header of col1 will contain an arrow (up arrow in this case).

```
grid.set("sort", [{attribute: col1, descending: false}, {attribute: col2, descending: true}]);
```

I could override `_setSort()` but the underscore tells me it's a private function...

Answer (score 0):

The underscore just means that the function should be *treated* as private, but that doesn't mean you *can't* override it. I would go forth and prosper with your override approach. :)